# Sufficient condition for differentiabilty of two variable, real valued function.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f: \mathbb{R^2} \mapsto \mathbb{R} \\$

Given that at $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ the partial derivative with respect to $y$ exists on a neighbourhood $U$ of $(a,b)$ and the one with respect to $x$ is continuous on this neighbourhood. Prove then, that $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$.

***My approach:***

Let $h,k$ be small enough so that $(a+h,b+k) \in U$.
Then write,

$ L=f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b+k)+f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)$

Now, $\  \displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b+k)}{h}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (a,b+k)$

Define: $\ g: \ [a,a+h] \mapsto \mathbb{R} \\ g(t)=f(t,b+k), 
 \ (t,b+k) \in U$

If $\ r \ $ be small enough then,
$\ \displaystyle \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{g(t+r)-g(t)}{r} \ $ exists.
Hence, $g$ is differentiable on $\ (a,a+h) \ $.

Applying LMVT on this interval gives:

$\displaystyle g(a+h)-g(a)=f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=h.g'(a+\theta h)=h. \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (a+\theta h,b+k),\ \theta \in (0,1) $

$\  \displaystyle \lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)}{k}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (a,b)$

So, I can write $\displaystyle f(a,b+k)-f(a,b)=k \cdot \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b) \ + e(k) \ $ where $e(k) \to 0$ as $k \to 0$.

Hence $\displaystyle L=h \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (a+\theta h,b+k) \ + k \cdot \frac{\partial f} {\partial y} (a,b) \ + e(k) $

Now, I need to show $\displaystyle \lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}\frac{L}{||(h,k)||}$ exists, but how do I proceed? I am getting stuck with finding the limit the first two terms of $L$, in particular.

Answer (score 1):

First: You know that $e(k)/k\to 0$ as $k\to 0$. Second, your proof seems to do the right thing — you do the usual proof, but make sure to vary $y$ first and then vary $x$.

But you really are looking at the wrong $L$. You want to look at
$$\frac{L-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)h - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)k}{\|(h,k)\|}$$
and show this goes to $0$ as $(h,k)\to 0$. With the usual observation that $\left|\dfrac{h}{\|(h,k)\|}\right|$ and $\left|\dfrac{k}{\|(h,k)\|}\right|$ are each bounded (along with $\dfrac{e(k)}{|k|} \to 0$), you'll have your proof.